# How to make an element beyond an other

Tags: html, css

Here is my code. I want my `<div id="home">` to be shown below my `<div id="navigate"`. What's the best way to achieve this?

```css
#home {
    background-color: black;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#navigate {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: grey;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-sheet/index.css"></link>
  <script src="scr/index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <div id="navigate">
    <div id="home">Home</div>
   </div>
   <div id="page">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"stackoverflow wants me to add details ... but what should i type?"_ Explain exactly what you are trying to achieve and how the actual result differs. Currently, you question makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly trying to achieve here?
Do you want the home text below the navigate div?
You can do that by simply  changing it to this:

```
<div>
    <div id="navigate">
    </div>
    <div id="page"> 
        <div id="home">Home</div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

This places the home inside of the page, you havent putten in any css for #page so im guessing thats just for all the elements below the navbar.